Can a single query that specifies a single record from a table, return multiple associated records from that same table?
I have a table of 'users' and a table of 'groups', and also a table of 'group memberships' tracking which users are in which groups.
I want to be able to start with a target user, and have the query return a list of all the users that have at least one group membership in common. It's no problem if the returned list of users includes the target user.
I can see how this could be done in multiple queries - query the group membership of the target user, then query each of the returned groups to get the members - but is it possible to do this in a single query? I don't see how I can return a list of multiple users when the 'WHERE' clause is specifying a specific user.
I don't need a complete solution, just to be told if this is:
A) Simply not possible in a single query, or
B) If it is possible, what approach(es) to try e.g. 'WHERE EXISTS'
I have tried to use 'WHERE EXISTS' with a subquery but I don't think I understand how to use it correctly or if it is even viable.

Please provide some sample data of the affected tables, the expected result of the query and your best attempt to solve it.

Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?

Yes, it’s possible. Just join users to groups, via the intersection table, and then join back to users

Too bad, I was an hour too late with my answer. I don't think there is anything unclear about your request. (But you should tag the DBMS you are using.) Unfortunately, people are rather quick with closing requests and rather slow with re-opening them, if ever. I'll post an answer illustrating the concepts, once this gets reopened.

I have removed the database tag, as yor request is not about designing a database. Please add a tag for your DBMS instead.

@ThorstenKettner I highly disagree with your opinion. The question is not clear at all to me. It misses a minimal reproducible example which is quite important to understand and replicate the issue. Why do you think people who ask something should not provide it? It misses furthermore their attempt to solve it. It's absolutely correct such questions are closed because it's much less effort that one person improves the question than 100 persons should find out what it means.

@Jonas Metzler: Well there is a table users, a table groups and a table group_memberships for the m:n relation. The question is: How to find all users that have at least one group in common with some user X. The OP has no idea how to express this in SQL, as is with many beginners, so they have not been able to write anything. They are guessing that an EXISTS clause may help, but they don't see how. Yes, sample data would illustrate this, but even without, I don't see anything unclear.

No one prevents them from adding sample data and the expected result to make things clearer and let the question be reopened.

@KeenanNV: Please see that in the commens above you are asked to show sample data. I suggest that you do this as a practice, albeit I have already answered your question. Readers of this request will benefit from this, as it will help them understand the task quicker and see whether it matches their own problem. (Make it a habit to provide sample data, then your requests won't get downvoted or even closed.) Thank you.

Yes, this is possible. And there are several ways to achieve this. One way is to use EXISTS as you suggest yourself. Another is IN, which does about the same thing. You can also use joins. And you can select data and then select from the result, i.e. select from a subquery or use a WITH clause.
What makes this task a little special is that you want to use the same table twice. The idea is: Give me the users that are member of a group where another member of that group is user X. In this phrase I am using the words "user", "group" and "member" multiple times. Let's see how a query with joins would look. I am calling the initial user UX and their membership MX here:
select distinct u.*
from users u
join group_memberships m on m.user_id = u.user_id
join group_memberships mx on mx.group_id = m.group_id
join users ux on ux.user_id = mx.user_id
where ux.name = 'Perry Rhodan';

You see, the key here is to give the tables aliases, so you can distinguish X from the other user and X's membership from the other user's membership.
As is, I am only selecting the found users from the users table, but have three joins that are only meant to delimit the result. And as a user can have more than one group in common with the user in question, we must get rid of duplicates via DISTINCT. This shows us that this query is not optimal. We are producing an intermediate result of all common memberships only to dismiss many rows later, because we are not really interested in that additional information. If we wanted to show the groups they have in common, too, then this would be the appropriate query.
But, as we only want to look up whether at least one common membership exists, we'll better use EXISTS or IN.
The query with an EXISTS clause:
select *
from users u
where exists
(
  select null
  from group_memberships m 
  join group_memberships mx on mx.group_id = m.group_id
  join users ux on ux.user_id = mx.user_id
  where m.user_id = u.user_id
  and ux.name = 'Perry Rhodan'
);

The same query with an IN clause:
select *
from users u
where user_id in
(
  select m.user_id
  from group_memberships m 
  join group_memberships mx on mx.group_id = m.group_id
  join users ux on ux.user_id = mx.user_id
  where ux.name = 'Perry Rhodan'
);

You can even drive this further: Looking for users that are in a member ship with a group for which exists a membership for the user in question:
select *
from users u
where user_id in
(
  select m.user_id
  from group_memberships m
  where m.group_id in
  (
    select mx.group_id
    from group_memberships mx
    where mx.user_id =
    (
      select ux.user_id
      from users ux
      where ux.name = 'Perry Rhodan'
    )
  )
);

In the end it is personal preference which query to use. They all work, and you'll find one more readable (and thus maintainable) than the others.
Here is yet another approach collecting memberships in common first and using these in the final query. With users A, B and C in group G1 and A and B also in group G2, we get the pairs A|B|G1, A|C|G1, B|C|G1 and A|B|G2 and also the reverse pairs B|A|G1, C|A|G1, C|B|G1 and B|A|G2, if we simply join on the group in common. We could of course do something about this, if we didn't want to get all those duplicates, but let's go with this data set for the moment. I am calling the user combinations we are getting "pairs" here:
with
  pairs as
  (
    select distinct m1.user_id as user1_id, m2.user_id as user2_id
    from group_memberships m1 
    join group_memberships m2 on m2.group_id = m1.group_id
  ),
  with_user_x as
  (
    select distinct p.user2_id as user_id
    from pairs p
    where p.user1_id = (select ux.user_id from users ux where ux.name = 'Perry Rhodan')
  )
select *
from user u
where u.user_id in (select with_user_x.user_id from with_user_x);

This is not the approach I would suggest for this task, as we have the same problem as with the initial query that we get all memberships in common that we must reduce with DISTINCT in order not to get a user more than once in the final result. But it helps illustrate how to get from a first query result step by step to the final result. For many complex tasks this step-by-step approach is a very good way to get to the result you are after.
